# An Apology: My first blog will be my last

Tags: discussion, blog

> The shoemaker's son always goes barefoot.
>
> -[16th century proverb](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O214-shoemakerssonlwysgsbrftth.html)

Between the two of them, the founders of Stackexchange have probably posted more to their respective blogs than all other startup founders combined.

So when I signed up to contribute to the GIS.SE blog, I assumed I would be using a user friendly environment integrated into the main site.  I was wrong.

**I apologize for not checking my assumptions before committing.**

For now I think my time is better spent answering questions on the main site than [asking wordpress questions on the meta site](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/how-do-i-post-code-in-the-blog).

Answer (score 4):

No pain, no gain...

AFAIK, this is the first time anyone's complained. Probably because there just haven't been that many blog posts with code in them. There are numerous ways in which that could be made easier, documented better, and made to correspond more closely to what you're already familiar with on this site.

But it won't happen until it's needed and asked for. Pioneers get the arrows in the back...

Comment: Shog9
a formal request is now here:
http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/645/could-we-install-the-syntaxhighter-plugin-for-the-gis-blog